# add commas to numbers in jquery counter with numeral.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, counter

i have counter here. It counts from 0 to given number on scroll. I need to add commas to numbers. It should be shown in like 234,235,235 instead of 234235235.

i've found a library [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/), it looks like it can do it, but i can't figure out where ti put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No libraries needed!

```
function comma(num) {
    var parts = num.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
};
```

Alternatively, by prototyping `Number`, so that you can use it like `num.comma()`:

```
Number.prototype.comma = function() {
    var parts = this.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
};
```

Note that the second method (extending a native) is generally considered to be bad practice. In practice, if you aren't using any libraries then it's fine, but otherwise it should be probably be avoided.

Comment: oh, thanks! should u place it in: 
            "from": {
                "count": 0
            },
                "to": {
                "count": data
            }
sorry, i'm really new to coding(

Comment: @NikolayPridachin I'm not sure what you mean. Could you edit your question to include some more of the relevant code?

Comment: sorry, i thougt that i added codepen link in my post, here is the code 
http://codepen.io/luisciphere/pen/YWOENr

Comment: @NikolayPridachin Add it on line 20 of your JS so you get `$(el).text(comma(Math.ceil(now)));`.